# ¿Como cerrar un form secundario sin perder su información?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy llamando un Form2 desde el evento de un botón en Form1:

```
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Form2 form2 = new Form2 ();
        form2 .ShowDialog(); }
```

Y en el Form2 tengo un numericUpDown1 al que le cambio el valor manualmente, pero al cerrar el Form2 con this.close() este valor se pierde, lo que quiero es que al volver a abrir el Form2 ese valor siga ahí que no se pierda.

Supongo que al cerrar el Form2 se pierde la instancia creada, y al volver a abrirlo se crea una nueva con el dato default del numericUpDown1, Alguien sabe la forma correcta de evitar esto?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrías crear una variable en la cual guardes dicha información y al momento de inicializar tu Form2 pasarlo como parámetro y agregarlo en tu numericUpDown1

Comment: @DanielHernandez gracias por la idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exacto al cerrar el `Form2` se destruye la instancia por lo tanto todas las variables internas.

Para no perder el valor podrias pasarlo al `Form1`, o podrias persistir el valor ingresado en una base de datos o archivo.

Si es en un archivo podrias usar

```
public void Form2_Closing(...){

   string fileName = @"c:\temp\datos.txt";
   File.WriteAllText(fileName, numericUpDown1.Text);

}
```

En este caso use el evento de cierre del form para grabar el valor, pero si tienes un boton para cerrar el form podrias usar ese evento click.

[File.WriteAllText Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Puedes usar el `File.RealAllText()` para recuperarlo

Si necesitas pasar el valor de un `form hijo` al `form padre` o sea quien lo invoco puedes hacerlo si tienes acceso a su instancia. Para esto en el Form2 (hijo) podrias definir

```
public class Form2 : Form{

    private IForm formPadre = null;

    public Form2(){
      InitializeConponent();
    }

    public Form2(IForm frm) : this() {
       this.formPadre = frm;
    }

    public vois button1_click(...){
       this.formPadre.setDato(textbox1.Text);
    }
}
```

En el Form1 (padre) implementas la interfaz

```
interface IForm{
   void setDato(string valor);
}

public class Form1 : Form, IForm {

   private string dato;

   public void buton1_click(){
       Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
       frm2.Show();
    }

    public setDato(string valor){
       dato = valor;
    }
}
```

Como veras usas la `interface` para desacoplar la comunicacion entre los forms, pasando la instancia en el constructor

Comment: Ok entonces entiendo que: no existe una manera propia de windows forms que permita interactuar de esta forma con un formulario hijo, sin que se pierdan los datos, como lo haría con un userControl con visible=true verdad?

Comment: no se que que te refieras con "manera propia", puedes pasar el datos de un form a otro si es lo que necesitas, pero si cierras ese form el dato se perdera

Comment: edite la respuesta para poner el ejemplo de como pasar datos de un form a otro

Comment: Gracias fue de mucha ayuda!